# How to set featured image in wp_insert_post

Tags: images, wp-insert-post

I have a register form with upload field and when the user registers i create a new post. I need to have the uploaded picture on the featured image of the post.

I have see something like this but i don't understand all :s

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$filename = basename($image_url);
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
else
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
 file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

But how to get the image url because the image is not yet sent ...